# django makemigrations to rename field without user input

Tags: python, django, rename, makemigrations

I have a model with CharField named *oldName*. I want to rename the field to *newName*.

When I run *python manage.py makemigrations*, I get a confirmation request **"Did you rename model.oldName to model.newName (a CharField)? [y/N]"**

However, I want to run the whole thing inside a docker container and there is no provision to provide the user input. Is there a way to force the migration without need for user input?

**PS:** I tried **--noinput** option with makemigrations. In this case migrations are not getting applied.

Comment: Migrations applied with `migrate` command.

Comment: I ran the `migrate` command after `makemigrations`

Comment: Why would you want to do this inside docker? Migrations are part of your source code.

Comment: That would be an option too. Even if I want to do it outside, is it possible to  skip the user input part. It would help if there are lot of such instances.

Comment: Try doing this `script_or_command < <(yes y)`.

Comment: This helped me. Thank you :)

Comment: You are welcome. Moved to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
script_or_command < <(yes y)
```

But I'm not sure this will work for multiple input prompts.

Comment: where should i add this sentence? if my docker-compose.yml file has this command `bash -c "python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"`

Comment: @Bito in your case it is better to use `--no-input` option for `makemigrations`. `bash -c "python manage.py makemigrations --no-input && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"`.

Comment: @Bito Also I suggest not using this pattern for `makemigrations`. It should be reviewed and applied manually

Answer (score 4):

Added `yes` and pipe `|` before command

> python manage.py makemigrations

inside the docker-compoase.yaml file and it should work as shown below:

```
yes | python manage.py makemigrations
```