# Django migrate and makemigrate automatic yes on prompt

Tags: django, django-migrations

Is there a way to automatically specify YES as the default option on

```
manage.py makemigrations myAPp and
manage.py migrate commands
```

i tried the --noinput option on migrate but i think it defaults to NO not YES

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django makemigrations to rename field without user input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39866339/django-makemigrations-to-rename-field-without-user-input)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

found the answer on another question

You can use the 'yes' command which passes a 'y' to all questions

```
yes | python manage.py makemigrations myApp
```

if you want to edit the response (i.e send a 'yes' instead of 'y') you can add it as a parameter

```
yes yes | python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 21):

Your migrations should run with the `--noinput` flag.

You may want to make sure you're migrating the same app that you've created the migrations for.

Try running `python manage.py showmigrations` before and after running your migrations to see what's going on.